# react-native passing ArrayBuffer or Uint16Array to native ReadableArray on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm receiving a PCM buffer from websocket onmessage method as `result`

```
    console.log('cleblanc length of TTS data ' + result.byteLength);
    const buff = new Uint16Array(result);
    console.log('cleblanc TTS data ' + buff);
    RNTtsPlayer.playTts(buff);
```

and my native method

```
  @ReactMethod
  public void playTts(ReadableArray readableArray)
```

It's causing `Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different`

I'd like to pass the data as a ReadableArray, but when I try using ReadableMap and passing `result` directly it results in the Java layer receiving an empty map.  Should I try converting it to a String or is there a way to make this work.

Comment: did you find any solution? i also facing this

Comment: YashVaghela I wound up converting to a string, I'll add an answer with the code below

Answer (score 1):

So I wound up converting the ReadableArray to a base64 string like this;

```
new Buffer(result).toString('base64')
```

And then simply decoding it in the Java like this;

```
samples[producerIdx] = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
producerIdx++;
```

Where samples is a `new byte[32][];`